# Android gradle build failing after migrating to v28.0.0 support libraries

Tags: java, android

After upgrading to the v28.0.0 Android support libraries (from 27.1.1), my build is failing with the following exception:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
```

caused by:

```
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesCompatParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImpl mImpl' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesCompat
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21Parcelizer: can't find referenced field 'android.media.AudioAttributes mAudioAttributes' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21Parcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mLegacyStreamType' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mUsage' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mContentType' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mFlags' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mLegacyStream' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
```

I've tried adding

```
-keep class android.support.v4.media.** { *; }
```

to my Gradle config but the error persists.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: set minify to `false` or try to find proguard rules for `androidx.media`

Comment: I would rather keep minification enabled.

Comment: Curiously, I've just ran gradle with  '--debug --scan' and the build is now succeeding even after removing those flags again.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I have the same problem, can you explain how to run Gradle with --debug --scan ? I have the warnings when I generate signed apk, so how to include these options ? Thanks

Comment: Hi Christian, command-line options can be set here:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Command-line Options

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but after adding these lines to my proguard-rules.pro file, it solve the problem :

```
-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I can't test it since the problem hasn't recurred but hopefully it's useful to others. Out of curiosity, did you also encounter the issue after migrating to the v28 support libraries?

Comment: why dontwarn if you keep them?